# How does pipx know which Python version to use?

Tags: python, pipx

I'm a strong `pyenv` and `poetry` user that's beginning to use `pipx` and looking to learn more about how it works. Specifically, I'd like to understand how it determines which Python version to use when installing.

I've noticed that it seems to search `PATH` for existing references to applications when you `pipx install <package>` to make existing installations accessible globally. This, for instance, works well with `pyenv` where it `pipx` will find a version of the package you install across any Python versions installed via `pyenv`.

```
pipx install cookiecutter
⚠️  Note: cookiecutter was already on your PATH at ~/.pyenv/shims/cookiecutter
  installed package cookiecutter 1.7.3, Python 3.9.6
  These apps are now globally available
    - cookiecutter
done! ✨  ✨
```

But what if it's a package you've never installed before? And there's a package version compatible with 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 – how will it determine with Python version to use when installing this package?

Answer (score 40):

I've found you can provide the Python version PipX should install the package into by providing it as an argument to the `install` command (see below).

More specifically, when using `pyenv`, you can switch to the version you desire to install into and then provide `$(which python)` to automatically provide the path to that python version...

```
pyenv shell 3.X.X
pipx install <package-name> --python $(which python)
```

Comment: You can also hard specify the python version running pipx in the first place with the format `python -m pipx` rather than just `pipx`, if you are maintaining multiple python versions. Pipx will need to be installed separately for each python version.

Comment: Seems not to work anymore. I've tired to install two different versions of poetry, since 3.6 is no longer supported. But `which python` results in `~/.pyenv/shims/python` no matter which is active

Comment: @MaKaNu works for me using `mise` e.g. 

`mise shell python@3.11` and then `pipx install visidata --python $(which python)`