# Github action using wrong version of Python

Tags: python, github, devops, github-actions, python-poetry

I have the following Github action, in which I'm specifying Python 3.10:

```
name: Unit Tests
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash
    working-directory: app
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Install poetry
    run: pipx install poetry
  - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
    with:
      python-version: "3.10"
      cache: "poetry"
  - run: poetry install
  - name: Run tests
    run: |
      make mypy
      make test
```

The `pyproject.toml` specifies Python 3.10 as well:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.10,<3.11"
```

When the action runs, I get the following:

```
The currently activated Python version 3.8.10 is not supported by the project 
(>=3.10,<3.11).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3 (3.10.5)
```

It would look like it's using 3.10, but `py.test` is using 3.8.10:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- 
/home/runner/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vital-background-pull-yluVa_Vi-py3.10/bin/python
```

For context, this Github action was running on 3.8 before. I've updated the python version in both the `test.yaml` and the `pyproject.toml` but it's still using 3.8. Anything else I should change to make it use 3.10?

Thank you

Comment: wild guess: move   actions/checkout@v3 to be the first step and see if that helps ?

Comment: I found that the problem might be in `pipx install poetry`: `installed package poetry 1.1.14, installed using Python 3.8.10`

Comment: Did you try installing poetry after setting the python version with the setup action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause is the section

```
- uses: actions/setup-python@v3
  with:
    python-version: "3.10"
    cache: "poetry"
```

with the line caching `poetry`. Since `poetry` was previously installed with a `pip` associated with Python 3.8, the package will be retrieved from the cache associated with that Python version. It needs to be re-installed with the new Python version.

You can either remove the `cache: poetry` from a single GH actions execution, or [remove the cache manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819132/5343387). This will fix your issue.

Comment: I don't think this is it. I set up the same thing with a new workflow, there's no cache, I am using `cache-dependency-path` explicitly, and you have to install poetry before setup-python or setup-python will fail because it calls `poetry env use`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Turns out it was the cache not being properly refreshed. I manually removed it and that solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pipx might install poetry using an unexpected version of python. You can specify the python version to use:

```
pipx install poetry --python $(which python)
# or
pipx install poetry --python python3.10
```

This is what I do after the `setup-python@v3` step.

You could also specify the path to the expected python version, [those are available in the github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-python#specifying-a-python-version). This would allow you to do the `cache: poetry` step in the order you have above.

I had a similar problem and solved it after reading [how does pipx know which python to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68735503/how-does-pipx-know-which-python-version-to-use). I did not use pyenv in my case, since I'm specifying version in my `setup-python@v3`.

You might also install poetry after the python setup step to be sure your version is available, supposing you did `python-version: "3.10.12"` or something. Then what remains is cacheing, perhaps [using the cache action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/cache) separately from the `setup-python` step.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happens because my `pyproject.toml` is in a subdirectory of the repository.

The log for my `actions/setup-python@v4` action looks like this:

```
/opt/pipx_bin/poetry env use /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.14/x64/bin/python

Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in /home/runner/work/PLAT/PLAT or its parents
Warning: 
Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in /home/runner/work/PLAT/PLAT or its parents
```

But the action completes successfully. Later, poetry doesn't know what python to use because it was unable to write to its global `envs.toml`. Eventually I did find that there's [an open issue for this](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/446) in `actions/setup-python`.

### Fix

##### Cheat

You can do one of two things. The simplest is a cheat:

```yaml
runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
```

The `ubuntu-22.04` image [has Python 3.10 baked in](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md), so you can just forget about switching pythons and that'll be ok for a while.

##### Actual Fix

The better fix is to add a step after `setup-python` but before `poetry install`:

```yaml
   - run: poetry env use ${pythonLocation}/bin/python
     working-directory: wherever/your/pyproject.toml/is
```