# How to completely uninstall pipx?

Tags: python, python-poetry, pipx

I tried using poetry with pipx. Poetry used the wrong python version so I deinstalled it and deinstalled the python version it was using so when reinstalled it would use Python3.10 instead of 3.9. Now without having Python3.9 I cant do anything with pipx. How do I completely uninstall it so it uses Python3.10?

[Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using (my path to my python version)]

Comment: What works depends entirely on how you installed it in the first place and which platform you are on. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Did you use `pyenv` to install Python? How did you install `pipx`?
Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68735503/how-does-pipx-know-which-python-version-to-use

Comment: py -3 -m pip install --user pipx
Thats how I installed it